# Trying to understand kotlin object code block

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I would like to understand the following code snippet:

```
@Bean
fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain? {
    val customPrincipalExtractor = SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor()
    customPrincipalExtractor.setSubjectDnRegex("OU=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
    val customAuthenticationManager = ReactiveAuthenticationManager { authentication: Authentication ->
        authentication.isAuthenticated = "Trusted Org Unit" == authentication.name
        Mono.just(authentication)
    }
    return http {
        x509 {
            principalExtractor = customPrincipalExtractor
            authenticationManager = customAuthenticationManager
        }
        authorizeExchange {
            authorize(anyExchange, authenticated)
        }
    }
}
```

from https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.1/reactive/authentication/x509.html.

My question is what does this block mean?

```
http {
    x509 {
        principalExtractor = customPrincipalExtractor
        authenticationManager = customAuthenticationManager
    }
    authorizeExchange {
        authorize(anyExchange, authenticated)
    }
}
```

How it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [type-safe builder pattern](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html). It is used in Kotlin mostly to create objects declaratively and/or provide a DSL by a library. It is one of the most advanced features of Kotlin, so it is not easy to explain in a few sentences, but above example works like this:

1. `http()` is a higher-order function that receives a lambda meant to configure `http` object.
2. `http()` executes this lambda, providing some kind of a "http scope" or "http builder" object to the lambda. Lambda receives this parameter as `this`, so we can access its members implicitly. (I don't know what is the specific type of this scope/builder object, you can check it by control-clicking on `http`)
3. Lambda can configure `http` object being created by accessing members of the provided scope/builder. `x509()` and `authorizeExchange()` are members of the builder or extensions on it. We can invoke them out of nowhere inside `http {}` block, because there the builder is our `this`, so all its members are resolved implicitly.
4. `x509()` and `authorizeExchange()` do the same thing as `http()`. They accept lambda and provide another builder to lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are asking about configures spring security. You have a `ServerHttpSecurity` object named `http` and you are setting configuration on it.

its equal in regular java would be something like:

```
http
    .x509()
        .principalExtractor(customPrincipalExtractor)
        .authenticationManager(customAuthenticationManager)
    .authorizeExchange()
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated();
```

First three lines are saying that we are going to be using x509 certificates, we have a custom principal extractor that we defined a couple of rows up which is a `SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor.html that needs to be used when we extract information from the certificate and build our principal object (all users after they are authenticate have a principal that contains who they are, etc.)

That particular extractor uses a regexp to extract the `subject`defined in the certificate.

the row after that we set a custom `AuthenticationManager` https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/latest/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html

There are several of these built into spring. For instance if you want to authenticate with username and password, or by presenting a token or a cookie, or by presenting a certificate you can a specific authentication manager. Or you can write a custom one if you want to authenticate someone in a specific way.

Last three lines say that any exchanges (requests) need to authenticated.